# jQuery Autocomplete Error: Property 'source' of object is not a function 

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, typeerror, uncaught-exception

I am trying to retrieve suggest queries from google's API and I keep getting an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object #<Object> is not a function`

The file is being parsed properly and in firebug/dev tools it shows that the callback is being retrieved without any errors. It seems to be an autocomplete error.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xrDjk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `source` attribute, since the jQuery UI autocompleter depends on it. There is an [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) in the autocompleter documentation. You can move your existing `.ajax` function as in the demo.

Comment: It actually makes no difference. This is a known working way.

Comment: Thanks for replying btw. I would give a bounty if you can provide a quick fiddle? Or I can make you one because I've tried it and it really doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Here is the version with source attribute sir: http://jsfiddle.net/XXcHE/ On this one I don't get console errors but yet again the autocomplete doesn't work.

Comment: @jQuerybeast We use the word "working" differently, I think ;) Sure *looks* like it's looking for a `source` attribute--but ok. In any case, it comes back with a `parseerror` response--the Google response is an array, not an object, apparently. I tried using `jsonp text` as the dataType but that didn't fix it.

Comment: So that's why my first method should work. It takes all the arrays and sets them into an autocomplete

Comment: @jQuerybeast Perhaps check out the [Google Suggest for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/googlesuggest-jquery/) project to save some effort--I think it's an issue w/ the returned data, but can't dig in to it now.

Comment: @jQuerybeast You *say* it should work, but it obviously doesn't, w/o the `source`.